# BEM nesting SCSS with parent selectors breaks Sublime Text syntax highlighting?

Tags: sass, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, bem

I'm experimenting with BEM syntax on a project that uses SCSS. My editor is Sublime Text 3 and I'm using SCSS syntax highlighting.

The problem I'm experiencing is that when I nest using the `&` parent selector as per [this article by Mike Fowler](http://mikefowler.me/2013/10/17/support-for-bem-modules-sass-3.3/), Sublime highlights it red. Here is an example:

[image]

The code compiles fine, I'd just prefer that Sublime not flag these as errors.

Can anyone help config Sublime to do just that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suggest using the [`Syntax Highlighting for Sass`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Syntax%20Highlighting%20for%20Sass) package for syntax highlighting. Using it and the [Neon Color Scheme](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme), which fully supports all the scopes in the Syntax Highlighting for Sass package (disclaimer: I'm the theme's maintainer), your code looks like this:

[image: SHfS and Neon]

with no errors (green is a class name, and `&` is recognized as a special SASS/SCSS symbol). I'm not sure what package you're currently using for SCSS highlighting, but it obviously doesn't recognize the leading `--` characters, or anything following leading `__` characters, as valid. Switching over to the new syntax highlighting package should help.

Comment: The Syntax Highlighting for Sass package was the answer I needed. I had been using the SCSS package, which didn't match the `&-someRule` selector syntax. The SCSS package has better autocomplete for hyphenated rules (e.g. `background-color`), so I'm using the two packages in tandem now.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this when I had this issue by selecting View>Syntax>SASS>SCSS This is apparently caused by downloading the original SASS package Sublime.